# FPDF won't create new page

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, fpdi

I need to create PDF file that is updating. Data is updated from time to time and every new data is placed on new line of document. Problem is that when first page of document is filled, my program won't create second page.

here is code that i am using

```
    $newRecord="Sample Data";
$sourceFileName="pdf.pdf";
$pdf = new FPDI();
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 0);
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile($sourceFileName);
//echo $pagecount;
for ($loop = 1; $loop <= $pagecount; $loop++) {
    $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage($loop);
    $pdf->addPage();
    $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0, 14);
}
$pdf->SetFont('Arial');
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->SetFontSize(14);
$pdf->Multicell(0,14,$newRecord);
$pdf->Output($sourceFileName, "F");
```

EDIT 1: Here is whole script that I am using

```
<?php
$newRecord="Sample Data";

  require_once('fpdf.php');
  require_once('fpdi.php');
function createNewPDF($newRecord){//this function creates pdf it there is no pdf crated
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',14);
$pdf->Multicell(0,14,$newRecord);
$pdfName=date('d-m-Y')."fitnessProgram.pdf";
$pdf->Output($pdfName,'F'); 
$today = date('Y-m-d'); 
$sql="INSERT INTO `pdf_files` (`id`, `date`, `expired`, `pdf_name`) VALUES (NULL, '$today', '0', '$pdfName')";
$sql_uname = mysql_query($sql) or die ('Unable to run query:'.mysql_error());
exit();
}
//function addNewRecord($newRecord){
include('db_connection.php');
$sql_uname = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `pdf_files`") or die ('Unable to run query:'.mysql_error());;
if (!mysql_num_rows($sql_uname) > 0) {
    createNewPDF($newRecord);
}
$sql_uname = mysql_query("SELECT `date`,`pdf_name` FROM `pdf_files` WHERE `expired`=0 LIMIT 1") or die ('Unable to run query:'.mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($sql_uname) != 0) {
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_uname)){ 
                    $date=$row["date"];
                    $sourceFileName=$row["pdf_name"];
                }
            }
if(strtotime($date)<strtotime('-30 days')){
     $sql_uname = mysql_query("UPDATE `pdf_files` SET expired=1 WHERE expired=0");
     createNewPDF($newRecord);
 }
$newRecord="Sample Data";
$pdf = new FPDI();
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 0);
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile($sourceFileName);
echo $pagecount;
for ($loop = 1; $loop <= $pagecount; $loop++) {
    $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage($loop);
    $pdf->addPage();
    $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0, 14);
    $pdf->setPageMark();
}


$pdf->SetFont('Arial');
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->SetFontSize(14);
$pdf->Multicell(0,14,$newRecord);
$pdf->Output($sourceFileName, "F");
//}

?>
```

Comment: Is `require('fpdf.php');` loaded?

Comment: yes it is. there is alot of other code. I cut that part

Comment: I use FPDF and I've never had a problem. Is this the first time you use it?

Comment: yes it is. I can't find solution anywhere....

Comment: How is your data being updated, from a text file, DB, other?

Comment: $newRecord="Sample Data"; every time i run script this variable ($newRecord) store "Sample Data" string to new line of pdf document. Simply when I run script i have string that needs to go on new line of document

Comment: Try adding `$pdf->setPageMark();` after `$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0, 14);`

Comment: error pop ups: atal error: Call to undefined method FPDI::setPageMark() in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\admin\pdf\tuto1.php on line 45

:(

Comment: Are both libraries loaded? I.e.: `require('addons/fpdf.php');
require('addons/fpdi.php');`

Comment: I added whole script. You can take a look at edited code now.

Comment: Are you trying to create a PDF from SQL data?

Comment: i am storing data to SQL but that data i want to write to PDF too. For each record in database that is added new line in PDF is created too. That's the point of script

Comment: I never used the other version that you're using now. I use the one at http://fpdf.org/ you should probably visit it and look at a few of the examples they have at http://fpdf.org/en/script/index.php and look for MySQL on that page. You can base yourself on those. From what I Google'd, one of your libraries may not be properly included, or you don't have them.

Comment: I ll try with mc_table script. Here is screenshot of directory where script is located: http://imgur.com/lsrHohe